# Using intent to use the camera inside app, but still crash

Tags: android

I need your help. I follow the instructions to use the camera inside the app on Android Developer, but my app crash. I can't even open the camera.

This is my code (The method *"goToCamera"* is called by *android:name="onClick"* in my activity.xml, so it takes in input a View object):

```
public class PostActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

static final int REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE = 123;
public static final int REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO = 1;
ImageView mImageView;

String mCurrentPhotoPath;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_post);
    Toolbar myToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.my_toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(myToolbar);
}

protected void goToHome(View view) {
    finish();
}

protected void goToCamera(View v) {
    Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
}
}
```

I already add this to my manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="true" />
```

I already try to use this:

```
Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
    startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
}
```

but it doesn't work. The app continue to crash.

Thank you so much.

Comment: is it crashing in oreo devices ? can u post error

Comment: I have nougat, android 7.0

Comment: can u post crash log ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need request for permission something like this.

```
protected void goToCamera(View v) {
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA}, CAMERA_PERMISSION);
    } else {

        Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    }
}
```

And in the activity you need to override onRequestPermissionsResult method for permission callback.

```
 @Override
  public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] 
     permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    if (grantResults.length > 0
            && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        goToCamera(null);
    } else {
        // permission denied, boo! Disable the
        // functionality that depends on this permission.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

your intent is correct and opening camera doesn't need any permission.

base on your log this is a problem with your onClick function.

change goToCamera to public method.

check the name of goToCamera function with the name on your android:onClick in xml